# Open .swf file in new window from other swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4

I have a button in a swf file. I would like that when the button is pressed a swf loads in another window (want to call a new swf in new window.).

I was trying something like:

```
MYBUTTON.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, MYBUTTON_link );

function MYBUTTON_link(e:MouseEvent):void
{

    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("external.swf");
    loader.load(urlRequest);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadDone);

}
```

other way was

```
   fscommand ("exec", "external.swf");
```

but none of them works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `navigateToURL` instead:

```
function MYBUTTON_link(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("external.swf"), "_blank");
}
```